# Why am I getting 100% accuracy for my logistic regression model?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Import the libraries

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn 
from sklearn import preprocessing
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
```

Reading the data

```
 df =pd.read_csv('./EngineeredData_2.csv')
    df =df.dropna()
```

Split the data into x and y:

```
X= df.drop (['Week','Div', 'Date', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam','HTHG', 'HTAG','HTR', 
            'FTAG', 'FTHG','HGKPP', 'AGKPP', 'FTR'], axis =1)
```

Trarnsoforming y into integers:

```
 L = preprocessing.LabelEncoder ()
    matchresults = L.fit_transform (list (df['FTR']))
    y =list(matchresults)
```

Split the data into train and test:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_tng,X_tst, y_tng, y_tst =train_test_split (X, y, test_size = 50, shuffle=False)
X_tng.head()
```

import the class

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
```

Instantiate the model

```
logreg = LogisticRegression ()
```

Fit the model with the data

```
 logreg.fit (X_tng, y_tng)
```

Predict the test data
        y_pred = logreg.predict (X_tst)

```
    acc = logreg. score (X_tst, y_tst)
    print (acc)
```

Does the accuracy make sense to be 100%?

Comment: If the problem is simple enough, sure. The result might also be caused by mistakes in dealing with your data. Without having seen your data, nobody can say for sure, though. Consider including a few samples from your training/validation set

Comment: We need some sample as @LukasThaler wrote above, but btw you wrote: `Split the data into x and y:`
Why you dropped `'Week','Div', 'Date', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam','HTHG', 'HTAG','HTR', 
            'FTAG', 'FTHG','HGKPP', 'AGKPP', 'FTR'`, but you use only `FTR`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you unintentionally dropped all of your features and only retained your target value in `x`. So, you are attempting to explain the target value with the target value itself, which of course will give you 100% accuracy. You defined your features columns as:

```
X= df.drop (['Week','Div', 'Date', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam','HTHG', 'HTAG','HTR', 
            'FTAG', 'FTHG','HGKPP', 'AGKPP', 'FTR'], axis =1)
```

But you should have defined them as:

```
X= df.drop('FTR', axis =1)
```